# How to read excel macros into Angular app

Tags: angular, excel, vba

I have a very complex excel sheet has a lot of macros and buttons to make some calculations. I need to import this sheet into angular app and with typescript access the macros and buttons and click them from angular.

I need to make this because I can't convert all the business in this sheet into normal web app so I upload it and take the data from the user via texbox and fill the sheet but I can't trigger the buttons click inside the sheet. In a short I make the excel as the brain which gives me the outputs and I show the output to the user.

I succeeded to read the file but without macros and shapes like buttons, imgs, ..etc.

```
var url = "assets/Foxboro.xlsm";
  var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
  debugger;
  oReq.open("GET", url, true);
  oReq.responseType = "arraybuffer";

  oReq.onload = function(e) {
  var arraybuffer = oReq.response;

  /* convert data to binary string */
  var data = new Uint8Array(arraybuffer);
  var arr = new Array();
  for(var i = 0; i != data.length; ++i) arr[i] = String.fromCharCode(data[i]);
  var bstr = arr.join("");

  /* Call XLSX */
 // var testDodo = XLSX.readFile(bstr, {bookVBA:true, /* .. other options */});
  var workbook = XLSX.read(bstr, {type:"binary", bookVBA:true});
  var workbook1 = XLSX.read(bstr, {type:"binary"});

  /* DO SOMETHING WITH workbook HERE */
  var first_sheet_name = workbook.SheetNames[2];
  /* Get worksheet */
  var worksheet = workbook.Sheets[first_sheet_name];
  let x = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(worksheet,{raw:true, header: 1 });
```

Comment: You cannot run any macros/VBA without Excel. The file needs to be opened in Excel to be able to trigger macros/VBA.

Comment: Flip it around and write VBA code that serializes the needed data and sends it as an http request to the web app?

Comment: I have the worksheet Object which has the sheets and the data inside but doesn't have all the data like buttons, imgs and other shapes, I need the missed data